# Loading a shared object library

Tags: c, freebsd

I have this little program that I took from some example around the web:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

   handle = dlopen("libzapi_v2.so.1", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
        printf("no handle \n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

   /* Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
       would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
       casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
       The assignment used below is the POSIX.1-2003 (Technical
       Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale for the
       POSIX specification of dlsym(). */
fprintf(stderr, "handle is here \n");

   *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");

   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I compile it with gcc -rdynamic -o np np.c and then when I run with ./np

I get the following error:

> ld-elf.so.1: assert failed: /usr/src/libexec/rtld-elf/rtld.c:1046
>   Abort (core dumped)

I search and searched for people with similar issues, but can't find anything. Can anyone offer some troubleshooting suggestions ?

This is on latest freebsd.

Comment: What is libzapi and where is it's source to the `cos` function that it apparently exported from it.  (Also, a little weird that a library would export `cos`, which is already a well known function from the standard C runtime)

Comment: Just initialize `cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");` without all the extra casting. It will compile fine.

Comment: 1. Try in non-lazy mode, and 2. `-rdynamic` is almost *never* necessary, and even when it is, it is usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: `*(void **) (&cosine)`? Of course C leaves this undefined just as well.

Comment: I tried without -rdynamic and still same output. The code was originally to written using libm.so just to illustrate the concept of loading .so then I switched it to libzapi_v2.so.1 library and this happens. dlsym is wrong as cos doesn't exist in libzapi_v2.so.1, but it doesn't even get there. I tried RTLD_NOW and same results after compilation.

Comment: Works for me (Debian/8, 32 and 64 bit; Aix6.1,32 and 64 bit): prints error message about the nonexistent shared library.